# Greedy algorithm to get highest score obtainable

Tags: r, optimization, greedy

I have an exam where the max pts is 55 and time limit is 50 mins. I need to devise a greedy algorithm in R to maximize the number of points obtainable in the allocated time.

assumptions:
-100% correct for questions attempted 
-once question started, it must be completed

I don't really know how to go about this one.

```
> table[order(table$Points_per_min, decreasing = T),]
  Question Total_Points Time_needed Points_per_min
6       Q6            5           3      1.6666667
5       Q5            5           4      1.2500000
4       Q4           14          12      1.1666667
7       Q7           10          10      1.0000000
8       Q8            5           5      1.0000000
1       Q1           21          24      0.8750000
9       Q9            5           6      0.8333333
2       Q2            5           7      0.7142857
3       Q3           10          15      0.6666667
```

I think based on calculations by hand, I should get 49 max points and 47 minutes used. I could be wrong. Thank you!

Comment: Your question is asking for two different things which aren't entirely compatible. A greedy algorithm will often get *close* to the maximum solution, but it's not guaranteed to find the exact maximum. I recommend looking for clarification on whether "greedy algorithm that gets close to the maximum" or "exact maximum" is required, since you can't do both at once. Fortunately you already have a good example for either of them in the answers!

Comment: yes, understood! it was the whole point of the assignment to prove that greedy doesnt always get you the most optimal solution. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set this up as a linear optimization problem. You are trying to maximize the number of points, subject to the time constraint. Further, each decision variable should be binary as you can't answer the same question twice.

`lpSolveAPI` is an R package to set these problems up. To be honest, I find the syntax a bit dense, but very powerful. I was able to find a 50 point solution that takes all 50 minutes. FWIW, I found the same solution in Excel's `Solver()`, which is a bit more intuitive in my opinion.

The full solution is below, but here's the representation of the model we've set up (this is the output from `write.lp()` after setting the model up:

```
/* Objective function */
max: +21 Q1 +5 Q2 +10 Q3 +14 Q4 +5 Q5 +5 Q6 +10 Q7 +5 Q8 +5 Q9;

/* Constraints */
Time_Constraint: +24 Q1 +7 Q2 +15 Q3 +12 Q4 +4 Q5 +3 Q6 +10 Q7 +5 Q8 +6 Q9 <= 50;

/* Variable bounds */
Q1 <= 1;
Q2 <= 1;
Q3 <= 1;
Q4 <= 1;
Q5 <= 1;
Q6 <= 1;
Q7 <= 1;
Q8 <= 1;
Q9 <= 1;

/* Integer definitions */
int Q1,Q2,Q3,Q4,Q5,Q6,Q7,Q8,Q9;
```

```r
library(lpSolveAPI)
library(data.table)

#Define questions, points, and time requirements
dt <- data.table(questions = paste0("Q", 1:9), points = c(21,5,10,14,5,5,10,5,5), time = c(24,7,15,12,4,3,10,5,6))

#make lp object with one contrasint and 9 decision variables
lprec <- make.lp(1,9)
#make sure we're maximizing, not minimizing
lp.control(lprec,sense='max')
#Set the names
dimnames(lprec) <- list("Time_Constraint", dt$questions)
#Set the objective function values, i.e. how many points we get
set.objfn(lprec, dt$points)
#assign the time taken to earn the points
set.row(lprec, 1, dt$time)
#what is the right hand side variable to 50
set.rhs(lprec, 50)
#make the variables binary
set.type(lprec, columns = 1:9, "binary")
#write this model out to see what it is
write.lp(lprec, filename = "model.lp", type = "lp")
#solve the model
solve(lprec)
#> [1] 0
#get the answers, i.e. which should be answered
answers <- get.variables(lprec)
#let's subset just the questions we should answer
dt[as.logical(answers), ]
#>    questions points time
#> 1:        Q1     21   24
#> 2:        Q4     14   12
#> 3:        Q5      5    4
#> 4:        Q7     10   10
#and confirm that we don't go over 50 minutes
dt[as.logical(answers), .(points = sum(points), time_taken = sum(time))]
#>    points time_taken
#> 1:     50         50
```

<sup>Created on 2019-02-10 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

*Greedy* approach here would be to solve the *questions* in *decreasing order of the points per minute*. It doesn't ensures to give you the best solution (optimum) as given by @Chase, but good enough. Only constraint is not to cross the time limit. If in process, you find a question that violates this constraint, you skip it.

```
# Initiate cumulative points 
cum_points <- 0

# Initiate cumulative time used
cum_time <- 0

# Initiating Questions solved/finished in sequence/ index j
question_finished <- as.character()
j <- 1


# sort the data based on Points_per_min
library(dplyr)
df_sorted <- df %>% arrange(desc(Points_per_min)) 

# Checking question by question
for(i in 1:nrow(df_sorted)){

     # only if cumulative time not exceeding time limit of 50 min, we solve a question
     if(cum_time + df_sorted$Time_needed[i] <= 50){
     cum_time <- cum_time + df_sorted$Time_needed[i]
     cum_points <- cum_points + df_sorted$Total_Points[i]

     # Storing the Solved/finished questions and incrementing j
     Question_finished[j] <- as.character(df_sorted$Question[i])
     j <- j + 1

  }
}

Question_finished
#[1] "Q6" "Q5" "Q4" "Q7" "Q8" "Q9" "Q2"
cum_points
#[1] 49
cum_time
#[1] 47
```

*Data Used:*

```
df <- read.table(text = "Question Total_Points Time_needed Points_per_min
6       Q6            5           3      1.6666667
5       Q5            5           4      1.2500000
4       Q4           14          12      1.1666667
7       Q7           10          10      1.0000000
8       Q8            5           5      1.0000000
1       Q1           21          24      0.8750000
9       Q9            5           6      0.8333333
2       Q2            5           7      0.7142857
3       Q3           10          15      0.6666667")
```

Comment: I like this solution too; the overhead in setting up a full LP may be overkill depending on the value of finding the truly “optimal” solution vs something that is good enough. The LP framework may scale better when there are more complicated constraints or objective functions, but likely problem specific.